# Odd Results using Bayesian Averaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, bayesian

I am using the following code to come up with a Bayesian average for my product reviews:

```
@bayesian = (((Review.count * Review.average(:score)) + (style.reviews.count +style.reviews.average(:score)))/(Review.count+style.reviews.count)).to_int
```

as per this discussion (scroll a third down the page):

http://blog.linkibol.com/2010/05/07/how-to-build-a-popularity-algorithm-you-can-be-proud-of/

Now strangely, these are the results that I'm seeing on my page:

[image]

Obviously by the logic of the article I should be seeing a product with 4 votes and an average score of 59% shown with a higher Bayesian than a product with 1 vote and an average of 50%.

Is there a problem with my implementation here?

Comment: is `Review.count` returning the total number of reviews instead of the correct average number of reviews per style?

Comment: No, Review.count is giving the total =(

Comment: can you post the equation you are trying to use from the blog. Because Im pretty sure it was supposed to be an average and not a total

Comment: You should mark your answer as "accepted" so this question will not be listed as an "unanswered" question.

Comment: It says I can't until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry everyone, the answer was simple in the end. I should have written:

```
@bayesian = (((Review.count * Review.average(:score)) + (style.reviews.count *style.reviews.average(:score)))/(Review.count+style.reviews.count)).to_int
```

Just needed to change that + to a * in:

```
style.reviews.count * style.reviews.average(:score)
```